How is my question deemed not seeking the history of the verse when it asks for its OT reference?
This is the question.
Exodus 32:33, Ezekiel 18:1-4; 20-24 and 26-27 seem contradictory to 1 John 2:2, are there OT verses supporting 1 John 2:2?
The question was swarmed by mostly pro Jesus is God comments and I address them according to reason using scriptures.
Why then was it deemed not seeking its history nor its answers when the question is asking for its reference in the Old Testament?

I hadn't seen the question or acted on it, but it looks to me to either be a verse search question or a systematic theology question, neither of which are on topic here.
Contradiction questions are a bit of an edge case - they don't really follow our general site rules, and they're more of a historical exception. We allow contradiction questions, but they have to basically just present the two seemingly contradictory verses and then let anyone present any kind of reconciliation that they like. Requesting a particular kind of reconciliation (such as asking for more OT precedents) moves it into systematic theology territory.
Even if it had been left as a pure contradiction question I would have closed it as unclear, as you did not explain what you think is contradictory. I can't see anything in those Ezekiel passages that even relate to propitiation.

Your question was not 'swarmed by mostly pro-Jesus comments'.
Jason did not name the name 'Jesus' nor did I. We were both trying to place the question properly.
You named the name 'Jesus', once, and Dottard responded, once.
Thus for four comments.

Then yourself and biff had a conversation in which you made 20 comments and they made 18.
I have not looked at that (TL;DR) so I cannot express a view.
I was intrigued by the concept behind the question and I placed it in SE-C as I felt that was where it belonged.
See What evidence was there, in Old Testament times, that the sacrifices being performed would be realised, actually, in the offering up of a humanity?
But I :

didn't make it a 'contradiction' question

didn't make it a controversial question

didn't try to make a theological point.


I just wanted an educated answer to a thoughtful question.
To date, one has answered but I am not convinced it is wholly relevant. Four people have up-voted. And someone has told me privately they are considering preparing a substantial response.
And, there is just one comment to which I have not responded.

It really comes down to 'what is our purpose here ?' and the results we achieve will reflect  :

what our objectives are

and the manner in which we seek those objectives.



I hope this is helpful to you.
